# JQuery append() doesn't append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I've got html structure like this:

```
<div id="things">
    <div class="whatever">
        <div class="frame">content</div>
        <div class="frame">content</div>
        <div class="frame">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I got JS with JQuery script that works on click on button on that page:

```
function intsaver(){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "intsaver.php", true);
    var tosf = $('<div></div>');
    $("#things").find(".frame").each(function(){
        tosf.append($(this).innerHTML);
        alert(''+tosf);
    });
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("data=" + tosf.innerHTML);
}
```

I can see `this` contents in debugger, they are exactly what I'm looking for. But `tosf` remains `undefined` and on server side I recieve `undefined`.

I've tried some ways, for examle, I appended `this` itself. As result, div's disappeared from page, but `tosf` remained `undefined`.

I believe I've made some obvious mistake.

Comment: Did you try var tosf = $('div'); ? I don't understand why you use '<div></div>'. I cannot imagine that will work.

Comment: @SylviaStuurman It's the way to create a new element in JQuery.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not realize that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change**

```
tosf.append($(this).innerHTML);
```

**To**

```
 tosf.append($(this).html());//$(this) a jQuery object
```

**Or**

```
tosf.append(this.innerHTML);//this a dom object
```

`$(this)` is a **`jQuery object`** not a **`dom object`** which doesn't have property **`innerHTML`**.Use **`.html()`** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function intsaver() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "intsaver.php", true);
    var tosf = $('<div></div>');
    $("#things").find(".frame").each(function () {
        tosf.append(this.innerHTML); //innerHTML is a property dom element
        alert('' + tosf);
    });
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("data=" + tosf.html()); //tosf is a jQuery object os call .html()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).innerHTML` should be `$(this).html();` and `tosf.innerHTML` should be `tosf.html()`

Reason is `tosf` and `$(this)` are *jQuery* style and `innerHTML` is pure *javascript*.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more explanation 'why `.innerHTML`' did not work. 
As it is stated in the answers, `$(this).innerHTML` would not work as jQuery does not have that property. But if you tweak your code you can benefit from `.innerHTML` as well. If you wrap an element with `$(element)` it creates jQuery specific object and you will need to get the element from it if you want to use `.innerHTML` like:  `$(this)[0].innerHTML`. As the `this` is only element in that jQuery array, `this.innerHTML` will be sufficient, without making `$(this)`. so your code can be:

```
function intsaver(){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "intsaver.php", true);
var tosf = $('<div></div>');
$("#things").find(".frame").each(function(){
    tosf.append(this.innerHTML);
    alert(''+tosf);
});
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("data=" + tosf[0].innerHTML);}
```